# Returning a line that has a regex on it

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a data that looks like this

```
data ="
john is 23 years old 
luca is 25 years old  
Samia is 25 years old 
"
```

I want to search for john and print the 23 years old

```
print(re.findall('john',data2))
```

this return john but I want to print 23 years old

Comment: split your text by line and use `contains`.

Comment: Just because a line contains the contains `john`, that's no guarantee it must contain `x years old`. This seems like a flawed assumption, in general.

Comment: It probably makes more sense to search for a pattern like `john is \d+ years old`